# Import Cookies in Selenium to login to Tiktok

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, tiktok

I want to import my TikTok Cookies in Selenium, so I can login without E-mail etc. I have my TikTok Cookies in json format. I got them with the Cookie Editor Extension. They look like this: (They don't work anymore, you can't steal my account)

```
[
    {
        "name": "ak_bmsc",
        "value": "8212602E930E6F64AA0624DD6E863C50~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQDkhnaHKTwhaFAQAAEIRhpxJcYa0shIEWLBmNGIiqgWbNUircx0QW4jdNl7F89wAEX8WzhDq5jvRnPvdpQPfRnF+CP/ICnJFmCue4JUra0oFm7nzRiYPXTGeqwIcmlgv+7B727AcUG9qs47fWGeF86muhpkRb6f1/FE7OfM3QnmonaDERcIaylhWE8/hHewg1TpqVdfTuXNv+U0RxiKz0zoYh3k5FusVB8Gi0NxgwbldEEKgXQDL9/xtBduCowdUP0zL55IA1kFeiwT9z+BYFzFZ4fP8Dc7HCjdhpiHGzfBfBltgHKwJjZIlZSxNGZL3hDt3O79BdMQSRMxobCbhePnCJ7SECkdGzPl7gTOrK6H7W+AXsjVfMpxOXJjh6dKC+7elGpJgL97M=",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1673557663,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "tt-target-idc-sign",
        "value": "5YxdfGLosvFdMgb1bXdwl1-FZzvdNya7FUu1ZT4HWrv3D_Cr3CMmxz92HBhdxocXBzBsdfOjE7ZCnwB8tEHmE7TO_Y7bRfD5X8a1FXR3CSgZrSu-Yh4m0g4VO3vxm9ZW4kUyNo8crey7ykJDvPerk_WXtmWHC2olcfK95CFMGSh2P12HmjK2bkCNwd8G67zIB9ruq8l3g6yP_wRwwe22TdU9seMC9Ej68Iv_aaOqvOLjjySEtKGgAITjeO7ILsZEeNcRRMzgs0zKlS5oHv0u34UY5BULmUq_u93KQsVhtD0MV918EjnXxyL0P0nzW3P14MD7o82iaHnhsYqgKGdQ2IuaUAt9-WRlZCEKjlz1qyGF7lMzJYAAcpdWeFvY8ngYrMweWs1FBUoUXdi2NC4abeH9-GA5hyDpufFG2gIpMJtduaN9_mbhqCsA5hzsUfKF5fHD5-PsTWGhk687sJA65pJODXhejGIh9pj7OO2kctvw0pMw7HIGp6rSq3W6t7Nd",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1705086503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "_abck",
        "value": "42D3C2D28425227E6C0BDE47B2356740~-1~YAAQBUhnaI4KwwWFAQAAhyhipwnW4qoS/PamAGRt5U3gP+fne8dib2iaTTsXfhJt27uYiaZHC8/Sj2nlhfx7w2rz9vVgfNYUpErbI+EvNCdrCitdoV1NDVaIQ4tjyP3ZOrsB9+CEtLbin+O9IfPHfxBdmU/9sbL73sM+4ht2uM55xsp4KSN7F/n6POqT7M+C73aPwmZJytQlzXLjIFLAGTFslRfr5yvMnwmlcxprokEMLUVCqunJ8qg2u9WPuoOkWzsD9qZn4CbwUQUz+PhXZl3/+niSB7ulOrDM3XQCR8YRivIr2JQT1V6uuxkKEfgGGKcDg0VJsITwY8/qzYYnbgM9cUl/7Ej29truMJiYDMUzNEPzMbcwYDl1nhMuIT2AIgoQEvmm7o/A7myM9F03vpbCrF+k/SyWAA==~0~-1~-1",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1705086507,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "csrf_session_id",
        "value": "9d94d54a439c43831d2ebb24e4023dbf",
        "domain": "www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": true,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": true,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "msToken",
        "value": "XD8GanFPqieP0PjK7ge-Odbup5gE6fYywLLdO8rQ_Uaz7_6QNkH36wNRlP898x8jixXc9lwofmuvzuZvimtWKg8UDIQw_XGDBzzzuIJj2uKx9NxnWIbMaWWrXl5qHPapTroL",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1674414517,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sid_guard",
        "value": "e5a873636ed0a691ad7b3ebe42b0b248%7C1673550501%7C5184000%7CMon%2C+13-Mar-2023+19%3A08%3A21+GMT",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1704654503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "ttwid",
        "value": "1%7CXYPMCdx97YCDwX5eXxScLqbcnCfWSV0NYr7S2XFUKYc%7C1673550510%7Cf31acce5c15c82d72348276034d4cc6ce6c9d43816c09f00e533b861d68081a0",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1705086511,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "store-country-code-src",
        "value": "uid",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734502,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "cookie-consent",
        "value": "{%22ga%22:false%2C%22af%22:false%2C%22fbp%22:false%2C%22lip%22:false%2C%22bing%22:false%2C%22ttads%22:false%2C%22reddit%22:false%2C%22criteo%22:false%2C%22version%22:%22v9%22}",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1704296770,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "uid_tt",
        "value": "ce2fbdf69c460a3daae4993581f1c1071a7d96da8a90bb7065a49f608177b88c",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "passport_csrf_token_default",
        "value": "521b10a4b8f43cbf5c6aea8119647675",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1674764431,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "msToken",
        "value": "XD8GanFPqieP0PjK7ge-Odbup5gE6fYywLLdO8rQ_Uaz7_6QNkH36wNRlP898x8jixXc9lwofmuvzuZvimtWKg8UDIQw_XGDBzzzuIJj2uKx9NxnWIbMaWWrXl5qHPapTroL",
        "domain": "www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": true,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1681326519,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "s_v_web_id",
        "value": "verify_lcm0ddcs_0DcAH7sq_9nJU_43jE_A6QK_ghq0EToUMZdj",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": true,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "store-idc",
        "value": "maliva",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734502,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "ssid_ucp_v1",
        "value": "1.0.0-KDk3ZjJhZTNkYzM0ZmNiNzg5YjAzZTdjNTM5NjZiYTU0N2U4NWRjZmEKHwiFiK2cnM-mtl8QpbWBngYYswsgDDCRtrL7BTgIQBIQAxoGbWFsaXZhIiBlNWE4NzM2MzZlZDBhNjkxYWQ3YjNlYmU0MmIwYjI0OA",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "tiktok_webapp_theme",
        "value": "light",
        "domain": ".www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1699470509,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "__tea_cache_tokens_1988",
        "value": "{%22_type_%22:%22default%22%2C%22user_unique_id%22:%227170793161920546309%22%2C%22timestamp%22:1669580405594}",
        "domain": ".www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1674155310,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "_tea_utm_cache_2643",
        "value": "undefined",
        "domain": ".www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1672415954,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "bm_mi",
        "value": "2030D375CF747A8B159C50AD67CD9418~YAAQw882F3ylm/CEAQAAuWStjBIwllCZO1L7WjSeIVaJc2Kj3d9ca5OeYKd6V62x9l7atKASNLV4YMWI/A70aVb8/dIIeeAM6MmC2mvrGxIEgaSGNv9nRjZ6gAZUl8i2w/is6pvGX5q3ZMWPOXSLfXlT+lJFVMiFPsZQq3FL7fOBQ709q482di7y1S3bBrGJmKyK9Um7QoQ/Ko40g0R+Bk0lxkiUJXw11AWq3Gz6N5r5bFD7STibHp0i8gZTlPB+z0ndZVdfHfcvxF1S9UbJ5gagzlQO9RIYYdtNtkizEw3nzUgMLd74R7QVd9bcjXhAzKKQS9OcuQ==~1",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1673106957,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "bm_sv",
        "value": "3F3B5DEE26756D70E68A9A13F04E6CC4~YAAQBUhnaJUKwwWFAQAA7V9ipxLydOaVu1dTtKoNtpWlMpoq5YYZXH+ViZ/K/KwtJnSviKaYv2Hh/LpJRg+/z4++gUhkoq3AF43/rsTBFWBQ7vzI/vnveu2cX5LwbMXAPY5/cdykiDMeFc6/wHh7w4AsuDESMwGHNExvgJW4ll97FXnZA4rczD4v7kKi2S7gt0L650Q8POBWcSNOQxJErU62gG+IycZ0OD7UMZEbI76HsAM6lESFqTzQNrT5k17q~1",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1673557711,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "bm_sz",
        "value": "B3CD421535E3ECAC5684BCE9FD5843F8~YAAQDkhnaHSTwhaFAQAAEIRhpxIzFkyZFUC0BE1leEQqpUQUCJWy7G5PV8Dcp2PvPJ/QxwcrULqnA2qtT11JnzhWPQKyVbg2mdZxyD3vPD6Xzk3jj0x1QswYTt6en646vXEUeSHy+cjXgFulgMO27Zw/OJDqRpp3wbgVd0vFqW9YVzd4MIzd+EZsS6jFgMswfhGOrXns8uiVHdUYeNDH3sTEAeSQ/DTs0WdaP0Uw/vfNBxXbwcTlwVLR6nEV7h0PrNG9Mh/T5EaX+5w7SCXTpvxUfhpHM3t67w6aM3S/VoRBC+U=~3749186~3293746",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1673564863,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "cmpl_token",
        "value": "AgQQAPOJF-RO0o9SdN5LuZ08-eJfUMmMP4cCYMoD6A",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "d_ticket",
        "value": "104fb2bea810b5a081aa9711d93bf4e4dc3b6",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1705086501,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "odin_tt",
        "value": "d202f5ea5cf2ba6774b02e1e1769dd372ba33f3c07c06c58bd1fd8f10eb381efdfb87e52db7b88f6340dca372e04bc34226db263ef5185bdad429b4bb6ee8fa318da837cba849c3f6eed37d113cc31cf",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1705086515,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "passport_auth_status",
        "value": "4c9d9171576cd640966ba95641afe9da%2C748dfc5c46868df08354d280de4b48ee",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1676142503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "passport_auth_status_ss",
        "value": "4c9d9171576cd640966ba95641afe9da%2C748dfc5c46868df08354d280de4b48ee",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1676142503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "passport_csrf_token",
        "value": "521b10a4b8f43cbf5c6aea8119647675",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1674764431,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "passport_fe_beating_status",
        "value": "true",
        "domain": ".www.tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": true,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionid",
        "value": "e5a873636ed0a691ad7b3ebe42b0b248",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionid_ss",
        "value": "e5a873636ed0a691ad7b3ebe42b0b248",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sid_tt",
        "value": "e5a873636ed0a691ad7b3ebe42b0b248",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sid_ucp_v1",
        "value": "1.0.0-KDk3ZjJhZTNkYzM0ZmNiNzg5YjAzZTdjNTM5NjZiYTU0N2U4NWRjZmEKHwiFiK2cnM-mtl8QpbWBngYYswsgDDCRtrL7BTgIQBIQAxoGbWFsaXZhIiBlNWE4NzM2MzZlZDBhNjkxYWQ3YjNlYmU0MmIwYjI0OA",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "store-country-code",
        "value": "at",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734502,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "tt-target-idc",
        "value": "useast1a",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734502,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "tt_chain_token",
        "value": "bNh130YMkpdYrSobdL0/zQ==",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1673572106,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "tt_csrf_token",
        "value": "1KPKsC8C-DV_gbCsZAXu5Vtc1G70rk0pa0BU",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "lax",
        "session": true,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "storeId": null
    },
    {
        "name": "uid_tt_ss",
        "value": "ce2fbdf69c460a3daae4993581f1c1071a7d96da8a90bb7065a49f608177b88c",
        "domain": ".tiktok.com",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "path": "/",
        "secure": true,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "sameSite": "no_restriction",
        "session": false,
        "firstPartyDomain": "",
        "partitionKey": null,
        "expirationDate": 1678734503,
        "storeId": null
    }
]
```

I tried this code, but it just didn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

print('get cookie')

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
with open('cookietest.json', 'w', newline='') as outputdata:
    json.dump(cookies, outputdata)

print('send cookie')

import json
from selenium import webdriver
with open('cookietest.json', 'r', newline='') as inputdata:
    cookies = json.load(inputdata)
curcookie = cookies[0]
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.add_cookie(curcookie)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.